# Customize Notification Email

Tags: cognito-forms

Under the Notification Email section, I can select "Include entry details?" When I do that, the content is garbled in the email received. No break points, etc.
I know I could pick and choose each field in the Message part, but when you have lots of data, and use multiple repeating sections, that could be a nightmare. In fact, when using repeating sections, I don't even see those as an option to include in the message area.

Are there any other ways to customize?

Answer (score 1):

The best option in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) for including entry details for complex forms (especially with repeating sections) is to include the entry details as a PDF attachment.